# Why does apt-get install duply (on debian 7.8) not update to the latest verison?

Tags: debian, apt, duply

Hi there I'm a bit confused about updating on my debian server. I'm using duplicity + [duply](http://duply.net/) on my server and wanted to update duply to the latest version. Running:

```
sudo apt-get install duply
```

Tells me that I have the latest version 1.5.5. The project website says 1.9.2 is the latest.

So why does apt-get not install 1.9.2?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This post on linuxquestions.org should explain the debian release process for you: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/is-debian-out-of-date-238023/#post1211402

Comment: Thanks @Sekenre I think I go for stable and keep out of trouble ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `apt-get` update to the latest version in the Debian repository, not the newest version of the upstream project.

In general, many/most Linux distributions do this, updates only are there to fix security issues, not to get the newest version.

Comment: Thanks. So I guess if I want to run the latest version I should install it manually. BTW Why the downvote?

Comment: It's generally not recommended to manually install software not in the repos to run on a server, unless you *really* need features of newer versions. If you do, it's now your task to regular check the project for security issues and then update your local install manually. On Debian, you might check into using `testing` or even `unstable` repos to avoid this, but I don't  recommend this (again, except you really need this and  then it's preferred over a manual install).

Comment: Okay. It's not that that important to have the latest. I was just curios because the version gap was that big. I'll stick with 1.5.5. Thank you